# Meaning of を with ようになる?

Tags: particle-を, passive-voice, transitivity

```
小学生の高学年の頃から、二人は関係を揶揄われるようになった。
```

What could this mean? Isn't ~ようになる intransitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93972/9831 Compare: 二人は関係**を**からかわ**れる** ~~ 私はパソコン**を**こわさ**れた** ~~ 私は財布**を**盗ま**れた**

Comment: Stupid me. I had forgotten that suffering passive forms of transitives take を.

Comment: I guess this can be closed has duplicate now.

Answer (score 2):

> What could this mean? Isn't ~ようになる intransitive?

While you're right that ようになる is 自動詞, but 揶揄{からか}う is not. You're parsing the sentence as :

> 二人は関係を [揶揄われるよう] になった。

Whereas it should've been

> 二人は [関係を揶揄われる] よう になった。